# How to use space as field separator using awk?

Tags: awk

Hereby I tried to output the column along with field separator.

But it fails in my case.

```
awk.txt(Input file)

Sr No Name Sub Marks
1) Amit Physics 80
2) Rahul Maths 90
3) Shyam Biology 87
4) Kedar English 85
5) Hari History 89
```

awk command which I tried as follows:-

```
 awk -F ' ' '{print $2 $3;}' awk.txt > output.txt
```

Obtained Output:

```
NoName
AmitPhysics
RahulMaths
ShyamBiology
KedarEnglish
HariHistory
```

Expected output:

```
    Name Sub 
    Amit Physics 
    Rahul Maths 
    Shyam Biology 
    Kedar English 
    Hari History
```

Comment: Are you running the commands on a DOS machine or) copy pasting from it? Your single quotes are unicode strings, which might not work on linux

Comment: am running  it in linux terminal @Inian

Comment: Ok, but the quotes are wrong, look at the quotes around `{}` and after `-F` the former is incorrect

Comment: In addition to the useful advice already present, you get "NoName" instead of "NameSub" because the header for the first column is apparently "Sr No", but you're using space as a delimiter. Don't put the delimiter as a character in a field value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
awk '{print $3,$4;}' awk.txt > output.txt
```

don't need indicate field separator. field numbers starts from 1, so you need third and fourth fields. and for print OFS (output field separator) use comma.

or:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=" ";}{print $3,$4;}' awk.txt > output.txt
```